# ES6 template literals bash continuation

Tags: ecmascript-6

I just found out that in ES6 template literals, doing this:

```
const template = `npm install \
&& npm start`;
```

Will result in this `npm install && npm start`. This is because a `\` at the end of a line is "escaping" the newline.

I am severely annoyed by this.

In bash and other things you would use `\` as a line continuation character. So you literally want the resulting string to be:

```
npm install \
&& npm start
```

Is there any way to remedy this?

Comment: Nothing special about template literals here, this also works in normal strings. And yes, you *always* have to escape the backslash.

Comment: You might want to try the `String.raw` tag.

Answer (score 4):

`\` is the escape character in strings and template literals. There is no way around this.

However, you can use the [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) **tagged** template. `String.raw` ignores escape sequences and returns them literally.

```js
const template = String.raw`npm install \
&& npm start`;
console.log(template);
```

---

However, you will still not be able to copy *every* bash command without modification. Bash allows you to refer to variables via the `${variable}` syntax. `${...}` is special inside template literals though, that's how substitutions are performed. So those would have to be escaped, but that only works in normal template literals or strings.

Comment: This String.raw function is good to know. Like you said it fixes my case pretty handily and I can still interpolate in there. In the end I think I have to live with some minor modifications being done to bash scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This gives me the result I want

```
const template = `npm install \\
&& npm start`;
```

I'm not totally happy with that. I am going to use ES6 template literals to generate files like Dockerfile, package.json, etc

My hope was that I could paste the file contents into the literal directly with no modification save the interpolated bits.

But I ran into this case immediately!